# How to write a record to memory and get it back in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL pseudo-code what I would like to achieve is:

```
type tTest is record
    A : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    B : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    C : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
end record tTest;
. . . 
signal sTestIn       : tTest;
signal sMemWrData    : std_logic_vector(fRecordLen(tTest)-1 downto 0);
signal sMemRdData    : std_logic_vector(fRecordLen(tTest)-1 downto 0);
signal sTestOut      : tTest;
. . .
sMemWrData <= fRecordToVector(sTestIn);
-- At some point sMemRdData gets the data in sMemWrData...
sTestOut <= fVectorToRecord(sMemRdData);
```

fRecordLen is an imaginary function that returns the aggregate length of record directly from the type and fRecordToVector and fVectorToRecord are hopefully self explanatory. The target is synthesizable code that doesn't produce any extra logic. I post my current solution as an answer to further clarify the operation. However this is extremely awkward method and I don't consider it as a feasible solution due to the amount of boiler plate code.

I am aware of [record introspection proposal](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/RecordIntrospection) but not holding my breath and even the proposed method seems very cumbersome.

I've given up hope for a fully general solution, so some concessions are more than acceptable. For example, allow only std_logic_vectors in the record and use several function/procedure calls. However, it would be great to avoid any boiler-plate code that must be hand or external script-adjusted per-record basis.

Also, if any Verilog/SystemVerilog wrappers exist that can input/output the record directly and achieve the same, pointers are extremely welcome.

Comment: Wow. Down vote without comment - sorry for not asking homework, but if this is too obvious or the example answer doesn't show research, do please please drop a comment or answer!

Comment: *Wow. Down vote without comment - sorry for not asking homework, but if this is too obvious or the example answer doesn't show research, do please please drop a comment or answer!* Hadn't you "given up hope"? Everyone complains about the weather but no one is willing to do anything about it. Write a package. Your example is one of two cases trotted out as justification for record introspection. Conversion mechanisms to/from arbitrary record types isn't possible. The subset that is, not eligible for inclusion in the language. Instead of using a record how about using subtypes defining fields?

Comment: _"how about using subtypes defining fields"_ would you have pointer or care to give an example? The record is not the main point, but somehow get more readable data from/to different signals that must be crammed to std_logic_vectors, so using something else that record is one of the concessions I'm willing to take.

Comment: The fact that I've given up hope is no indication of whether or not solutions exist...

Answer (score 1):

One way to translate data from a vector (a linear array) to a record would be through the use of an aggregate.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package TestPck is
    subtype A is std_logic_vector (12 downto 9);
    subtype B is std_logic_vector  (8 downto 1);
    subtype C is std_logic_vector  (0 downto 0);
    constant ABC_len: natural := A'length + B'length + C'length;
    type tTest is record
        A:  std_logic_vector (A'RANGE);
        B:  std_logic_vector (B'RANGE);
        C:  std_logic_vector (C'RANGE);
    end record tTest;
    type tTests is array (natural range <>) of tTest;
end package TestPck;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.TestPck.all;

entity tb is
end entity tb;

architecture sim of tb is
    signal sTestIn:        tTest;
    signal sMemWrData:     std_logic_vector(ABC_len - 1 downto 0);
    signal sMemRdData:     std_logic_vector(ABC_len - 1 downto 0);
    signal sTestOut:       tTest;
    constant tests:        tTests (0 to 1) :=  
             (0 => (x"E", x"A7", "1"), 1 => (x"7", x"AC", "0"));
begin
    sMemWrData <= sTestIn.A & sTestIn.B & sTestIn.C;
    sMemRdData <= sMemWrData after 5 ns;
    sTestOut <= 
        tTest'(sMemRdData(A'range), sMemRdData(B'range), SMemRdData(C'range));
process is
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        sTestIn <= tests(0);
        wait for 10 ns;
        sTestIn <= tests(1);
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture sim;
```

The qualified expression defines the aggregate as a value of tTest record with positional association which is assigned to the record type sTestOut.

And this gives:

[image: tb.png]

So you can use concatenation for assembling a vector value (or an aggregate in -2008) and use an aggregate as a qualified expression to transfer sMemRdData to sTestOut.

If you have no plans to declare an object of an A, B or C subtype you can declare them as integer subtypes:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package TestPck is
    subtype A is natural range 12 downto 9;
    subtype B is natural range  8 downto 1;
    subtype C is natural range  0 downto 0;
    constant ABC_len: natural := A'left + 1;
    type tTest is record
        A:  std_logic_vector (A);
        B:  std_logic_vector (B);
        C:  std_logic_vector (C);
    end record tTest;
    type tTests is array (natural range <>) of tTest;
end package TestPck;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.TestPck.all;

entity tb is
end entity tb;

architecture sim of tb is
    signal sTestIn:        tTest;
    signal sMemWrData:     std_logic_vector(ABC_len - 1 downto 0);
    signal sMemRdData:     std_logic_vector(ABC_len - 1 downto 0);
    signal sTestOut:       tTest;
    constant tests:        tTests (0 to 1) :=  
             (0 => (x"E", x"A7", "1"), 1 => (x"7", x"AC", "0"));
begin
    sMemWrData <= sTestIn.A & sTestIn.B & sTestIn.C;
    sMemRdData <= sMemWrData after 5 ns;
    sTestOut <= 
        tTest'(sMemRdData(A), sMemRdData(B), SMemRdData(C));
process is
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        sTestIn <= tests(0);
        wait for 10 ns;
        sTestIn <= tests(1);
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture sim;
```

This may be a little easier to read. It'll produce the same waveform above.

Comment: This neatly gets rid of the slicer procedure and allows the declaration of the constant inside the package - so 2 out of 3 problems solved! However, the code might be a bit neater with declaring subtype stA and then in record just have A: stA. This seems to work - is there some benefit using the std_logic_vector(A'range) in the record instead of the subtype?

Comment: Now I can see that the biggest downfall is the fact that the range is not downto 0. I was able to make that without manual calculations with functions, but now that using these elements, the "downto 0" is so much in the second nature that I continually make mistakes in slicing the record elements.

Comment: Ah! I think I got it - using constant instead of subtype and 'lenght-1 downto 0 instead of 'range in record does the trick. Also, function calls for both (from) and (to), not a single one tidies it up. I can post full answer, although don't want step on the toes of user1155120 - the solution is definitely his/hers.

Answer (score 0):

This a one way to achieve what is requested. The shortcomings/improvement ideas are in the comments.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
package TestPck is
    type tTest is record
        A : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        B : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        C : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
    end record tTest;
    procedure pSliceToFrom (
        signal vec_to   : out   std_logic_vector;
        signal vec_from : in    std_logic_vector;
        position        : inout integer
    );
end package TestPck;

package body TestPck is
  procedure pSliceToFrom (
    signal vec_to   : out   std_logic_vector;
    signal vec_from : in    std_logic_vector;
    position        : inout integer
    ) is
  begin
    vec_to   <= vec_from(position-1 downto position-vec_to'length);
    position := position-vec_to'length;
  end pSliceToFrom;
end package body TestPck;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.TestPck.all;

entity tb is
end entity tb;

architecture sim of tb is
  signal sTestIn       : tTest;
  -- How to create this constant in the package, 
  -- i.e. without needing the signal?
  constant cTestLength : integer := sTestIn.A'length + sTestIn.B'length + sTestIn.C'length;
  signal sMemWrData    : std_logic_vector(cTestLength-1 downto 0);
  signal sMemRdData    : std_logic_vector(cTestLength-1 downto 0);
  signal sTestOut      : tTest;
begin
  -- How to make this without needing to know what 
  -- is inside tTest?
  sMemWrData <= sTestIn.A & sTestIn.B & sTestIn.C;
  -- Memory, Fifo, communication link, doesn't matter...
  sMemRdData <= sMemWrData after 5 ns;
  -- How to get the data back without needing this
  -- process (and the procedure)?
  slice_data_to_item : process (all) is
    variable vPosition : integer := 0;
  begin
    vPosition := cTestLength;
    pSliceToFrom(sTestOut.A, sMemRdData, vPosition);
    pSliceToFrom(sTestOut.B, sMemRdData, vPosition);
    pSliceToFrom(sTestOut.C, sMemRdData, vPosition);
  end process slice_data_to_item;

process is
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        sTestIn <= (x"E", x"A7", "1");
        wait for 10 ns;
        sTestIn <= (x"7", x"AC", "0");
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture sim;
```

Comment: You seem to have [missed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VZNM.png) the fVectorToRecord part.

Comment: Its the slice_data_to_item, [wave here](http://imgur.com/a/AOwgP) naturally not the function -- that is the problem that I try to find out how to do.