# Is function call in defining a constant valid VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

In relation to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745104/how-to-write-a-record-to-memory-and-get-it-back-in-vhdl) I tried to make slicer that would declare constants with increasing range. The code below seems to have correct functionality, but it seems that the operation is not stable.

The compiler does give a warning:

> (vcom-1515) Prefix of predefined attribute "range" is function call "ifRange"

And referring to the constant with attribute 'range seems to be unstable, while 'left and 'right is working properly.

Is this valid VHDL? Any other ways to achieve the same?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package RangePack is
  impure function ifRange(a     : integer;
                          reset : boolean := false)
    return std_logic_vector;

  type tProtectedInteger is protected
    impure function Get return integer;
    procedure Set(a : in integer);
    procedure Add(a : in integer);
  end protected tProtectedInteger;

end package RangePack;

package body RangePack is

  type tProtectedInteger is protected
    body
      variable vInteger : integer := 0;
    impure function Get return integer is
    begin
      return vInteger;
    end function Get;

  procedure Set(a : in integer) is
  begin
    vInteger := a;
  end procedure Set;

  procedure Add(a : in integer) is
  begin
    vInteger := vInteger + a;
  end procedure Add;

end protected body tProtectedInteger;

shared variable svOffset : tProtectedInteger;

impure function ifRange(a     : integer;
                        reset : boolean := false)
  return std_logic_vector is
  variable vDummy  : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
  variable vOffset : integer;
begin
  if(reset) then
    svOffset.Set(0);
  end if;
  vOffset := svOffset.Get;
  svOffset.Add(a);
  return vDummy(vOffset+a-1 downto vOffset);
end ifRange;

end package body RangePack;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.RangePack.all;

entity tb is
end entity tb;

architecture sim of tb is

  constant cB : std_logic_vector(ifRange(8, reset => true)'range) := (others => '1');
  constant cA : std_logic_vector(ifRange(4)'range) := (others => '0');

  signal sVector : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0) := x"CA7";

  signal sA : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal sB : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

begin

 -- works
  sA <= sVector(cA'left downto cA'right);
  sB <= sVector(cB'left downto cB'right);

  --does't work
  --sA <= sVector(cA'range);
  --sB <= sVector(cB'range);

end architecture sim;
```

Comment: An alternative way might be to define a constants for the field widths and a constant for the word width from those, avoiding the use of protected types. The use of a protected type doesn't appear necessary here. Your assignments `--doesn't work sA <= sVector(cA'range);  --...` are legal in your present example.

Comment: It's legal VHDL. IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.2.3 Predefined attributes of arrays A'RANGE [(N)] "Prefix: Any prefix A that is appropriate for an array object, or an alias thereof, or that denotes an array subtype whose index ranges are defined by a constraint. There are no warnings defined in VHDL, legal means error free. The legality can be determined at elaboration time. A way to cure the warning would be to create two functions to return the two bounds separately. I.e. do not rely on the 'RANGE with a prefix who's legality can only be determined at run time...

Comment: I think the warning is not caused by the commented-out part, but by this: e.g. `ifRange(8, reset => true)'range`. Here the prefix of the `'range` attribute is a function call. But what do you mean with "operation is not stable"?

Comment: Yes as the title says, the question is about the constant definition part. "Not stable" is referring to using the 'range, like in the commented out part. Similarly there are run-time errors from various use of 'range. Error messages are clearly indicating that the range is gone haywire, like "left side 13 downto 2 is not part of -200 downto 99"...  It almost seems that the simulator calls the function every time the 'range is referenced.

Comment: Are you showing us all your code? Nowhere I see a range 13 downto 2...

Comment: [VHDL-2017](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/VHDL_2017) adds [record based ranges](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/TopLCS2016_099) as a new feature. Are you interested in writing a package to implement user defined arithmetic on ranges? You can find my contact information [here](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/AUTHORS.md)

Comment: Indeed - the error is from a range that isn't part of the code.